# Transfer between projects models in JSON format, Model Binder

Tags: asp.net

If you type in the browser link /APIA/GetA/a/a/a/a the data (modela2) in json displayed.

```
{
  "id11": "a",
  "id22": "a",      
}
```

The first project of trying to convey the model modela second project and get modela2.

modela passed in the second project.

The first project back modela2 can not get.

On this line does not return data

```
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(APP_PATH + "/APIA/GetA", modela).Result;

return response.StatusCode.ToString();
```

> readm2
>
> NotFound

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
```

> false

Project 1:

```
string readm2 = GetModelA2(token);
Console.WriteLine("readm2");
Console.WriteLine(readm2);


static string GetModelA2(string token)
        {
            using (var client = CreateClient(token))
            {
                //
                var modela = new ModelA { };
                ...

                var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(APP_PATH + "/APIA/GetA", modela).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Parse the response body.
                    var p = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ModelA2>().Result;
                    //Console.WriteLine("{0}", p.Name);
                    return p.ToString();
                }
        }
    }
```

Project 2:

```
[RoutePrefix("APIA")]
    public class APIAController : ApiController
    ...
    [Route("GetA/{id1}/{id2}/{id3}/{id4}")]

        public ModelA2 GetA([ModelBinder]ModelA modela)
        {
            ...
            var modela2 = new ModelA2 { };
            ...

            return modela2;
        }
        //




public class ModelA
    {
        public string id1 { get; set; }
        public string id2 { get; set; }
        public string id3 { get; set; }
        public string id4 { get; set; }     
    }

public class ModelA2
    {
        public string id11 { get; set; }
        public string id22 { get; set; }        
    }
```

Comment: Methods are name as Get, but you are doing HTTP Post. It is really confusing. Did you forget **[HttpPost]** attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Error corrected.

It changed like this:

2

[HttpPost]

[Route("PostA/{id}/{name}")]

public Game2 PostA([ModelBinder]Game game)

1

var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(APP_PATH + "/APITest/PostA/i/i", game).Result;